# Why window.scrollY !== document.body.clientHeight @ maximum scroll point

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll

Why isn't window maximum scroll equal to body height?

I am trying to do some effect with the friction between the maximum scroll and current scroll.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `window.scrollY` will give you the coordinate of the left top corner. You will see that if you add the height of the window to `window.scrollY` at the max scrolling point, you will have the height.

**Example :**
My window has as an `innerHeight` of `599`,
My `body` has a height of `1797`,
The value of `window.scrollY` at the maximum scrolling point is `1198`,
If I do `1198 + 599` I obtain `1797` that is the right height of my document.

`1198 + 599 = 1797`

Just keep in mind that the value of `window.scrollY` is in the top left corner of the document.

Answer (score 1):

See [`Element.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight):

> The `Element.clientHeight` read-only property is zero for elements with
>   no CSS or inline layout boxes, otherwise it's the inner height of an
>   element in pixels, including `padding` but not the horizontal scrollbar
>   `height`, `border`, or `margin`.
>
> `clientHeight` can be calculated as CSS `height` + CSS `padding` - height of
>   horizontal scrollbar (if present).

There might be a `margin` assigned to the body.

Answer (score 1):

[The clientHeight property returns the viewable height of an element in pixels, including padding, but not the border, scrollbar or margin.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_clientheight.asp)

[The read-only scrollY property of the Window interface returns the **number of pixels that the document is currently scrolled vertically**.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)